# Find a partial string in a cell and return exact value using a formula?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I need some help on this. I would like to find two different partial strings in a cell using a formula.
For example - if cell (A1) contains "Staples A-12345 Georgia, USA" or other cell may contain only "g345" or "g100, g000" or other times it contains both A-12345 g345 in a cell as an example.

My goal is to return a value of "GXXX" or if not present, use the "A-XXXXX".

Search A1 cell for partial text of "A-" or "G". (The "A-, must contain 7 characters" and "G, must contain 4 characters.)

- If true, C1 to return value of GXXX or if that is not present, use the other one.
- If it contains multiple codes (GXXX, GXXX) then return both values separated with a comma
- If it contains both "A-" and "G" in a cell, grab only the "G" code.
- If cell blank, return blank value.
- If cell value does not contain both "GXXX" or "A-XXXXX", copy and return the same value.

I am currently using this formula. I am unable to display the actual string.

```
=IFS(
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*A-*",A1)),"TRUE",
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*G*",A1)),"TRUE")
```

I got confused and stuck on this.Your time and help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would the regex `.*(([Gg][0-9]{4})|([Aa]-[0-9]{7})).*` meet all the requirements of the GXXX/A-XXX ? I keep feeling like I am missing something when I read through the question.

Comment: @deef0000dragon1, my goal is to have a return value of either GXXX or A-XXXXX. Those two are codes and they are not always the same. Sometimes, we would multiple codes of GXXX, so I am hoping to get a return value of those codes separated by a comma.

Comment: =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*(([Gg][0-9]{4})|([Aa]-[0-9]{7})).*") ... I see this message: Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value ".*(([Gg][0-9]{4})|([Aa]-[0-9]{7})).*" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "Staples A-12345 Georgia, USA".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IFNA(IF(A1="",,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "(g\d{3}).*(g\d{3})|(g\d{3})"), TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
  REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(g\d{3}).*(g\d{3})|(g\d{3})")), REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "A-\d{5}"))), A1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there a way to make the formula case sensitive? I tried the formula with variation, still not picking up the correct info. Here is a sample test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xznoTAH2yS-Xnf-b3cCc0j8vxa9jS10WP1HjQapzNw/edit#gid=1669877142

Comment: try: `=IFNA(IF(A1="",,
 IF(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A1), "(G\d{3}).*(G\d{3})|(G\d{3})"), TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
  REGEXEXTRACT(UPPER(A1), "(G\d{3}).*(G\d{3})|(G\d{3})")), REGEXEXTRACT(UPPER(A1), "A-\d{5}"))), A1)` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf1Gt.png

Comment: Thank you @player0. Looks like the updated formula works. Super!